# How can I transform this circuit so that the output voltage not depending on the supply voltage of the amplifier(V2 and V1)?

Tags: schmitt-trigger

[image]I have to modify this circuit so that the amplitude of the output signal be the same,everytime I change the value of V2 and V1...How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of feeding the amplifier output back to R2 and Runlabelled, put a resistor in series with the amplifier output, and a pair of back to back silicon diodes to ground, and connect R2 and Runlabelled to those. This will regulate the feedback voltage to roughly +/- 0.7, as long as V1 and V2 are sufficiently above that. Or use end to end Zeners, if 0.7v is too little.